# How to do Attribute Routing in ASP.Net MVC4 and Web API 1 Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

Is there any way to do attribute Routing in ASP.Net MVC4 and Web API 1 project? I have search so much about that only solution I found was update or install the project to MVC5, Web Api 2 and AttributeRouting. I tried to do it from nuget but having issues with supporting older version packages in the project(Install-Package AttributeRouting, Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi, Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc). Is there any way to do attribute routing with out updating or installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid compatibility issues it is advised to update to a more recent version that supports attribute routing.

I used the following walkthrough to successfully upgrade my ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2

[How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to run both ASPNET MVC & Web API using Attribute Routing, but [minimum version for Web API is v2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

So your only road to use Attribute Routing is to upgrade you Nuget packages, at least for Web API.